# catkin package build error

Tags: ros, catkin, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to build `slam_gmapping` in catkin workspace. I had cloned and build `openslam_gmapping` package but i am getting below error.
I was able to find openslam_gmapping from `rospack find openslam_gmapping`. I am using `ros groovy`

```
    -- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 2 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - gmapping
-- ~~  - slam_gmapping (metapackage)
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'gmapping'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(slam_gmapping/gmapping)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package openslam_gmapping.

  Set openslam_gmapping_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for openslam_gmapping.  The file will have one of the following names:

    openslam_gmappingConfig.cmake
    openslam_gmapping-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  slam_gmapping/gmapping/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'slam_gmapping'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(slam_gmapping/slam_gmapping)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

**Edit**

Operating System - Ubuntu 12.04

openslam_gmapping cloned from https://github.com/ros-perception/openslam_gmapping

I tried `apt-get install ros-groovy-openslam-gmapping` but not working.

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120231/catkin-package-build-error/) by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3034 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kamiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5346/kamiccolo/) on 2014-01-21**:
Could You please, be more specific on details like: 1. Operating System. 2. Where did You installed it (openslam_gmapping) from sources? (it smells like an issue with not following the Catkin Workspace directory structure). 3. Did you source the setup.bash file which was created in the place you installed it to before trying to compile with it? 4. If it's Ubuntu, have You considered simply `apt-get install ros-groovy-openslam-gmapping`?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-21**:
@Kamiccolo i updated the question for 1,2,4 question. I didnt source setup.bash

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-01-21**:
Do you have your catkin workspace initialized properly (see 'http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace'). Plz source setup.bash in your catkin_ws/devel folder. If you create a simple package and than a second package that depends on your first package, do they find each other?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-21**:
@Wolf After doing source devel/setup.bash build is proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have your catkin workspace initialized properly (see 'http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace'). Plz source setup.bash in your catkin_ws/devel folder.

You can check your workspace being properly initialized by creating two simple packages in your workspace where one package depends on the other. If they find each other the workspace is Ok.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!! Since you have cloned the repository from github, so you have that package. Follow the following steps, you can build package without error,

1. `catkin_create_pkg <pkg_name> roscpp`
2. Go to src folder in that package
3. Paste the packages you downloaded from github.
4. now, `catkin_make --pkg <pkg_name>`

Let me know if it does not work.

Thank You.

---

Originally posted by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) with karma: 88 on 2018-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-17**:
Hi @mallikarjun: +1 for making the effort to post here, but what you suggest is not necessary, nor the recommended way to do it.

If you download the pkg from github, you can immediately build them (provided you have installed the dependencies). No need to run `catkin_create_pkg` first.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-17**:
Further: you should be very hesitant to build packages from sources. Using `apt` to install them is almost always preferable.

**Comment by [yashmaurya](https://answers.ros.org/users/50466/yashmaurya/) on 2019-12-24**:
Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @bvbdort, If you want to install the source code of gmapping in your workspace.
you just need to do the following steps,

Download the source code from the following link via zip file and unzip the file
https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/tree/groovy-devel .

Then, copy-paste the source code of gmapping into your workspace.

Before building the workspace you should run the following command, **sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-openslam-gmapping** It helps to install the following files for gmapping.

```
openslam_gmappingConfig.cmake
openslam_gmapping-config.cmake
```

If you have any queries please leave your problem here.

---

Originally posted by [Kothandaraman Kannadasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71126/kothandaraman-kannadasan/) with karma: 26 on 2021-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1